# ggVennDiagram: counting binary items and displaying three sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, counting, venn-diagram

The clinical experiment has 10 people give blood samples at three defined time points (`t1,t2,t3`). Not everyone was able to come to their appointment, so some people missed one or more of the samples, which is shown as "0". Others were at all three samples (`t1` = "1", `t2` = "1", `t3` = "1").

My goal is to create a Venn Diagram using the `ggvenndiagram` pacakge with every intersecting area showing the number of people that gave their sample at the defined times (sets `t1, t2, t3`).

So in the middle is the fraction of people that gave all three requested samples. In the outer areas, without intersections, are the people that managed only one sample (e.g. subject Nr. 8 managed only the sample at `t2`, this should be displayed as "1" / "10 %" respectively. 4 people gave all three samples, so the middle of all three circles should show "4" / "40 %" respectively, for details see below).

Code&data:

```
library("ggVennDiagram") 
t1<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0) 
t2<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0) 
t3<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0) 
cbind(t1,t2,t3)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```r
ggVennDiagram(apply(cbind(t1, t2, t3), 2, function(x) which(x == 1)))
```

[image]

Note that people who did not show up for any visits can't easily be recorded, as they do not belong to any set (and there is no mechanism that I can find to assign to a "null" set), so the percentages are the percentage of people who participated.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: At which place in your code do I insert "lty", "color" etc. in order to customize the plot?

Comment: You can use `edge_lty` and `edge_size` inside the call to `ggVennDiagram`, and to change colours, you can do `+ scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow", "brown", "pink"))` as you would with a ggplot.

Comment: `ggVennDiagram(apply(cbind(t1, t2, t3), 2,
                    function(x) which(x == 1)), category.names = 
                c("Probe 1", "Probe 2", "Probe 3"),
              edge_size = 0.2, label_size = 3, set_size = 3) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#F4FAFE", high = "#4981BF")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black"))`  worked out. But the catagory names won´t display with their entire titles, but were cut off by the edges/margins of the plot. Is there a call to minimize the size of the circles or how do I cope that problem?